# Setup cookies in flask request unittest without client

Tags: unit-testing, flask

I am writing unit-tests for my flask application. I have couple of method which not aimed to return response, but it is actively using cookies. For example:

```
def get_timezone():
  try:
    return int(request.cookies.get('timezone_offset', 0))
  except (RuntimeError, ValueError):
    pass

  return 0
```

My test looks like:

```
from my_main import my_flask_app
with my_flask_app.test_Request_context(**request_environ_params):
  tz_value = 4
  # HERE. How to setup cookie value to `tz_value`?

  tz = myapp.utils.get_timezone()
  self.assertEqual(tz, tz_value)
```

So, I want to setup cookies (how to setup other request parameters I am already figured out) for testing purposes. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The test client has a `set_cookie` method, does something like this work?

```
with app.test_client() as c:
    c.set_cookie('localhost', 'COOKIE_NAME', 'cookie_value')
    resp = c.get('/my_url')
```

Comment: I am testing server-side functionality which cannot be tested with `test_client` so this approach does not applicable at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful:

```
with app.app_context():
    with app.test_request_context():
        resp = make_response(redirect('your_url'))
        resp.set_cookie('Cookie_name', 'Cookie_Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.
The cookie should in `headers` which is a key of `**request_environ_params`

```
cookie = http.dump_cookie("Cookie_name",'Cookie_value')
with app.test_request_context(path="/", method="GET", headers={"COOKIE":cookie}):
    # do_something...
```

I think you can know my answer.

:P(I'm not good at English)